# How to increase Height and width params of a layout dynamically with a button click?

Tags: android

I have a layout to whom I gave a hardcoded height and width. I have plus and minus buttons on layout and trying to increase height and width but it's not working for me. Here is my xml Layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/floating_play_layout_scene">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/floating_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:src="@drawable/float_close"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/float_playbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/floating_video"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/floating_video"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/floating_video"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/floating_video" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:src="@drawable/full_screen"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_enabled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/min_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic__remove_enabled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/add_btn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

this is how I'm increasing height and width dynamically

```
addbtn.setOnClickListener {
            height.plus(10)
            width.plus(10)
            params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                width,
                height,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )

        }
```

And how I'm assigning these params to window manager

windowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params)

Comment: I think according to your code you need to use ViewGroup instead or WindowManger

Comment: can you provide code of your xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in your button click event :-

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rel_inc_dec.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = layoutParams.height + 50;
            layoutParams.width = layoutParams.width + 50;
            rel_inc_dec.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: This worked but setting params is taking so long and stuck UI

Answer (score 0):

The already answered code is ok but a better approach to solve the above problem would be to update your window manager in your setOnClickListener method.

```
addbtn.setOnClickListener {
        height.plus(10)
        width.plus(10)
        params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            width,
            height,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
       **windowManager.updateView(mFloatingView, params)**
    }
```

And this would remove your problem of stuck UI.